# Visual Studio 2010 Intellisense annoyances

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

In VS2010 when my intellisense (for C#) pops up the first selected item is not highlighted. This means i have to press down/up-arrow before i press dot/enter/parenthesis to get the full word.

This only happens with the new intellisense (the one that searches everywhere and not only in the beginning).

Also, how do i switch between the old and new intellisense? This seems to happen automatically sometimes so i guess there's some hotkey i keep pressing all the time without knowing.

Comment: Hi Johoo, you may wish to mark answered questions as such.

Answer (score 11):

You can go to Edit -> IntelliSense -> Toggle Completion Mode. I thought there was a keyboard shortcut for it, but it appears not on my current installation... that may be a side-effect of installing ReSharper though. You can always set a shortcut if you want one, of course.

Comment: Thank you! The hotkey is listed in my menu and is ctrl+alt+space.

But it would be even better to get the old behavior with the new filtering.

Comment: @Johoo: Interesting - Ctrl-Alt-Space was my guess, but I didn't include it as it isn't in my installation :) I don't know about mixing and matching different aspects, I'm afraid.

Comment: It may automatically switch back to the (IMO) less useful mode, though - *In some IntelliSense scenarios, suggestion mode is used even if you do not enable it.*, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exbffbc2.aspx).